# How to execute an rxjs transformation operator only if a condition is met with angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I want to verify a coupon code with an API call to the server but first I have to check user session because I need the user is logged in with a valid session token. If the session has expired I want to show a login dialog and complete the stream possibly without enter in the next callback of the subscribe function, if the session is still valid I want to call the API to validate the coupon and execute the code in the next callback of the subscribe function.

```
applyCouponCode() {
  const user = this.auth.getUser();
  if (user) { //verify if user is logged in
    if (this.couponCode.length !== 0) {
      this.auth.checkSession() //API call to verify if user session is still valid
        .pipe(
          tap((sessionValid) => {
            if (!sessionValid) {
              //session expired
              this.auth.clientLogout();
              this.auth.showLoginDialog();
            } else {
              //session valid, call the API to validate the coupon code
              mergeMap(() => this.reservation.validateCouponCode(this.couponCode, user.token));
            }
          })
        )
        .subscribe(
          discountCode => {
            if (discountCode.valid) {
              //create the discount code obj and apply to user cart
              ....
            } else {
              //notify discount code is invalid to the user
              ....
            }
          },
          error => {
            console.log('error', error);
          }
        );
    } else {
      this.emptyCouponSubmitted = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Another possible solution is to refactor the operators in the pipe function

```
.pipe(
  tap((sessionValid) => {
    if (!sessionValid) {
      this.auth.clientLogout();
      this.auth.showLoginDialog();
    }
  }),
  mergeMap((sessionValid) => {
    if (sessionValid) {
      return this.reservation.validateCouponCode(this.couponCode, user.token));
    } else {
      // I would like to complete the stream without enter in the next callback
      return of(null);
    }
  })
```

I would like to enter in the subscribe next callback only if the API to validate the coupon code was called and I want to complete the stream if the session of the user has expired. Is it correct? Are there better ways to execute the mergeMap operator based on previous condition and to complete the stream if that condition was not met? What is the best practice to manage these kind of situations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to my issue. I have added a filter operator between the tap and the mergeMap operators

```
.pipe(
   tap((sessionValid) => {
     if (!sessionValid) {
       this.auth.clientLogout();
       this.auth.showLoginDialog();
     }),
     filter(sessionValid => sessionValid),
     mergeMap(() => this.reservation.validateCouponCode(this.couponCode, user.token))
)
```

Doing this, if the session is expired (sessionValid is false) I'm able to show the dialog  without calling the mergeMap operator because the value emitted is filtered by the filter operator and the stream completes without enter in the next callback of the subscribe function, otherwise mergeMap is called and I can manage the result of the new stream in the subscribe function.